# How to Implement Nested Filters in a Supabase Query with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, nested-filters, query-building

I am currently working on a Flutter application where I need to perform a Supabase query with multiple levels of filters. The goal is to dynamically generate an endpoint based on the applied filters. Here is the code snippet I am using: :

```
Future<List<dynamic>> fetchJobData(
  List<int> countryList,
  List<int> cityList,
  int category,
  int subCategory,
) async {
  // Add your function code here!
  // Use await inside an asynchronous method
  // final data = await Supabase.instance.client.from('jobs').select('*');
  // print("GOt DATA ${data}");
  // return data;
  try {
    var query = Supabase.instance.client.from('jobs').select(
        '*,city:cities!inner(name_ar,name_en,id,country:countries!inner(id,name_ar,name_en)),job_category_rel:job_category_rel!inner(id, category!inner(id,name_ar,name_en))');

    if (countryList.isNotEmpty) {
      query = query.in_("city.country.id", countryList);
    }
    if (cityList.isNotEmpty) {
      query = query.in_("city.id", cityList);
    }
    if (category != 0) {
      query = query.eq("job_category_rel.category.id", category);
    }
    if (subCategory != 0) {
      query = query.eq("job_category_rel.category.id", subCategory);
    }

    final data = await query.order("created_at");
    var jsonString = jsonEncode(data[0]);
    debugPrint('DATA ARE : $jsonString', wrapWidth: 500);

    // Assuming data is List<dynamic>, cast it to the expected type
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> typedData =
        data.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return typedData;
    // return data;
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error fetching data: $e");
    throw e; // Rethrow the error to inform the FutureBuilder
  }
}
```

The code works well when no filters are applied. However, when I trigger a filter, such as the country filter under the first if statement, I encounter the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Map<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'toList'.
```

Comment: error is clear. depending on parameter of query it returns single object map rather than list.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the data as the data is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. No need to do any type-casting.

```dart
return data;
```